# All treecolumns are not editable in a tree in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have implemented a tree and also add 5 treeColumn in SWT. Now programmatically expand this tree by using parent treeItem and child treeItem. Now I want to edit all the columns. When I write a code for this, I only get first column for edit, the rest of the columns are not eligible for that. Please suggest how I will get all columns are editable. Please find the below code:

```java
private void editTreeTable(final Tree table) {

    final TreeEditor editor = new TreeEditor(table);

        editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;

        editor.grabHorizontal = true;

        table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) 

                        Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
                        if (oldEditor != null) oldEditor.dispose();
                        TreeItem item = (TreeItem)e.item;

                        if (item == null) return;

                        // The control that will be the editor must be a 
                        Text newEditor = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);

                        newEditor.setText(item.getText());

                        newEditor.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                                        Text text=(Text)editor.getEditor();
                                        editor.getItem().setText(text.getText());
                                }
                        });
                        newEditor.selectAll();
                        newEditor.setFocus();
                        editor.setEditor(newEditor, item);`
                }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge here is knowing which column has been selected. One way to accomplish this is by using a `MouseEvent` and getting the corresponding `TreeItem` and column index from the coordinates of the `MouseEvent`.

Taking a look at the `Tree` class, we find the method [getItem(Point)](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Tree.html#getItem(org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point)), and the `TreeItem` class provides the method [getBounds(int)](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TreeItem.html#getBounds(int)).

Using `getItem(Point)` with the `Point` from the `MouseEvent`, then iterating over the column count (See: [Tree.getColumnCount()](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Tree.html#getColumnCount())) and passing the index to `getBounds(int)`, we can easily identify the `TreeItem` and column index to provide to the [TreeEditor.setEditor(Control, TreeItem, int)](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/TreeEditor.html#setEditor-org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control-org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem-int-) method.

For example (modifying your code slightly and adding some comments for clarification):

```
// Use a MouseListener so that we can get the widget-relative x,y coordinates
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent e) {
        final Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
        if (oldEditor != null) {
            oldEditor.dispose();
        }

        // Get the Point from the MouseEvent
        final Point p = new Point(e.x, e.y);
        // Get the TreeItem corresponding to that point
        final TreeItem item = table.getItem(p);
        if (item == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Now that we know the TreeItem, we can use the getBounds() method
        // to locate the corresponding column
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
            if (item.getBounds(i).contains(p)) {
                final int columnIndex = i;
                // The control that will be the editor must be a
                final Text newEditor = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);

                newEditor.setText(item.getText(columnIndex ));

                newEditor.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                    public void modifyText(final ModifyEvent e) {
                        final Text text = (Text) editor.getEditor();
                        editor.getItem().setText(columnIndex , text.getText());
                    }
                });
                newEditor.selectAll();
                newEditor.setFocus();
                // Set the editor for the matching column
                editor.setEditor(newEditor, item, columnIndex );
            }
        }
    }

});
```

---

Full MCVE:

```
public class TreeEditorTest {

    private final Display display;
    private final Shell shell;

    public TreeEditorTest() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final Composite baseComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        baseComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        final Tree table = new Tree(baseComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        final int columnWidth = 100;
        new TreeColumn(table, SWT.NONE, 0).setWidth(columnWidth);
        new TreeColumn(table, SWT.NONE, 1).setWidth(columnWidth);
        new TreeColumn(table, SWT.NONE, 2).setWidth(columnWidth);
        new TreeColumn(table, SWT.NONE, 3).setWidth(columnWidth);
        new TreeColumn(table, SWT.NONE, 4).setWidth(columnWidth);

        final String[] strings = new String[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5" };

        final TreeItem parent = new TreeItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        parent.setText(strings);

        final TreeItem child1 = new TreeItem(parent, SWT.NONE);
        child1.setText(strings);
        final TreeItem child2 = new TreeItem(parent, SWT.NONE);
        child2.setText(strings);

        parent.setExpanded(true);

        final TreeEditor editor = new TreeEditor(table);
        editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent e) {
                final Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
                if (oldEditor != null) {
                    oldEditor.dispose();
                }

                final Point p = new Point(e.x, e.y);
                final TreeItem item = table.getItem(p);
                if (item == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
                    if (item.getBounds(i).contains(p)) {
                        final int columnIndex = i;
                        // The control that will be the editor must be a
                        final Text newEditor = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);

                        newEditor.setText(item.getText(columnIndex ));

                        newEditor.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                            public void modifyText(final ModifyEvent e) {
                                final Text text = (Text) editor.getEditor();
                                editor.getItem().setText(columnIndex , text.getText());
                            }
                        });
                        newEditor.selectAll();
                        newEditor.setFocus();
                        editor.setEditor(newEditor, item, columnIndex );
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    }

    public void run() {
        shell.setSize(600, 200);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        new TreeEditorTest().run();
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3300205/avojak Thanks for your valuable feedback. it works now.

Comment: @Biswabir Great, glad I could help, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider accepting this answer if you found that it solved your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3300205/avojak
Hi, i want to create drop down list(Combo box viewer) in treeItem. How is it possiple. please help.

Comment: @Biswabir that is beyond the scope of this question or answer. Feel free to make a new question and I or someone else may be able to help.